# app doesn't install in iOS devices

Tags: codenameone

I've built an debug mode ios in cn1 which works well in all the iOS devices up to version 10 but it doesn't work above iOS version 11. I've tested it in iOS 6+ & others. It says unable to download app.

build hint:

[image]

Comment: What build hints did you include in the app. Is the device within the list of the devices in the provisioning profile?

Comment: Have a look at the build hints above... Yeah I've included the Udid of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `ios.debug.archs=armv7` flag. You built a 32bit app which will no longer install in newer devices.

Comment: I've removed it but it doesn't install in both newer and older devices...

Comment: Do you have push in your provisioning too?

Comment: How to look that? In the app id identifier in the apple account, there is push notification configurable selected.

Comment: Then yes that should be it. In that case my best suggestion is to get a hold of a Mac and look at the xcode output when you are trying to install